# Installing ritz-nrepl for emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm trying to setup ritz-nrepl to use emacs as a clojure debugger.

I have lein 2. I got emacs 24.2.1 (fresh install) and clojure-mode. Then I did what the readme says here https://github.com/pallet/ritz/tree/develop/nrepl under nREPL debugger installation (putting stuff in `init.el` and `.lein/profiles.clj`) and then did `M-x nrepl-ritz-jack-in`. I got the output below. Am I doing something wrong? I have only done what I said, nothing more. Maybe I'm missing a step?

```
Could not find artifact robert:hooke:jar:1.1.2 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Retrieving robert/hooke/1.1.2/hooke-1.1.2.jar (3k)from https://clojars.org/repo/

Retrieving leiningen/leiningen/2.0.0-preview10/leiningen-2.0.0-preview10.jar (165k)

    from https://clojars.org/repo/

Retrieving leiningen-core/leiningen-core/2.0.0-preview10/leiningen-core-2.0.0-preview10.jar (21k)

    from https://clojars.org/repo/

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

    at clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.findClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:61)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

    at ritz.jpda.jdi$eval1039$loading__4784__auto____1040.invoke(jdi.clj:1)

    at ritz.jpda.jdi$eval1039.invoke(jdi.clj:1)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6501)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6952)

    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:359)

    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:350)

    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:429)

    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)

    at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)

    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)

    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)

    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)

    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)

    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5298)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)

    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)

    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1096)

    at ritz.jpda.debug$eval888$loading__4784__auto____889.invoke(debug.clj:1)

    at ritz.jpda.debug$eval888.invoke(debug.clj:1)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6501)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6952)

    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:359)

    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:350)

    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:429)

    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)

    at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)

    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)

    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)

    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)

    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)

    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5298)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)

    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:605)

    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5392)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:3659)

    at ritz.nrepl$eval5$loading__4784__auto____6.invoke(nrepl.clj:1)

    at ritz.nrepl$eval5.invoke(nrepl.clj:1)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6501)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6952)

    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:359)

    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:350)

    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:429)

    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)

    at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)

    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)

    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)

    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)

    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)

    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5298)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)

    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)

    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)

    at user$eval1.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6501)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6500)

    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6477)

    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2797)

    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:297)

    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:316)

    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:349)

    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:427)

    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)

    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)

    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)

    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)

    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)

Subprocess failed
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing tools.jar from the classpath, you'll find it in the lib directory of your JDK (not JRE).

Comment: I think this answer can be phrased more succinctly as "Install the JDK".

Comment: I have installed the JDK, and I copied it into my projects classpath, but no difference. Or, maybe I should say copied it into my projects lib/ dir. I don't know how emacs/nrepl-ritz-jack-in handles the classpath.

Comment: Hm I messed about with my PATH for another issue, and now it works. Can't remember exactly what I changed. :P

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has this problem this is how I solved it
(it was a little more complicated than just installing the JDK)

1. Install the JDK. I put it in C:\jdk1.7.0
2. Use `lein-localrepo` to install it as a local jar as follows:
3. Add `:plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.4.0"]]` to your user profile in `.lein\profiles.clj`
4. `lein deps`
5. `lein localrepo install "C:/jdk1.7.0/lib/tools.jar" "com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine" 1.7.0`
6. Make sure `lein-localrepo` can find the jar. `lein localrepo list | grep jdi` should show: `com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine (1.7.0)`
7. Add `:dependencies [[com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine "1.7.0"]]` to your user profile
8. `lein deps`
9. In emacs, `nrepl-ritz-jack-in` should now work correctly